# Hartl's railstutorial.org Chapter 5, exercise 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm ploughing through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout) right now and found an issue I can't google fix.

Upon creating this file: `test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb`, and running:

```
'rails test'
```

I'm getting this failure:

```
AIL["test_full_title_helper", ApplicationHelperTest, 0.7209667120041559]
 test_full_title_helper#ApplicationHelperTest (0.72s)
        --- expected
        +++ actual
        @@ -1 +1 @@
        -"Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
        +"Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
        test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb:6:in `block in    <class:ApplicationHelperTest>'
```

Having browsed similar questions, albeit questions over a year old (and using older Rails code), I'm none the wiser as to how to rectify this failure.

I am clearly a Ruby noobie, so please be gentle :) any help would be greatly appreciated

**static_pages_controller_test.rb:**

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should get home" do
    get root_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get help_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get about_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get contact" do
    get contact_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end
end
```

and the offending file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test "full title helper" do
    assert_equal full_title,         "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    assert_equal full_title("Help"), "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end
end
```

and the site_layout_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
    get contact_path
    assert_select "title", full_title("Contact")
  end
end
```

and the code for the application_helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
    def full_title(page_title = '')
      base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
      if page_title.empty?
        base_title
      else
        page_title + " | " + base_title
      end
    end
  end
```

help.html.erb static_page:

```
<% provide(:title, "Help") %>
<h1>Help</h1>
<p>
  Get help on the Ruby on Rails Tutorial at the
  <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/help">Rails Tutorial help section</a>.
  To get help on this sample app, see the
  <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/book"><em>Ruby on Rails  Tutorial</em>
  book</a>.
</p>
```

Comment: can you post the `full_title` method? it is hard to figure out what is wrong if we are just seeing the tests.

Comment: I mean show us the `full_title` method you wrote in the `ApplicationHelper`

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to show one of the static pages (the help, about, or contact page)

Comment: Cheers. I've edited above, added ApplicationHelper module.

Comment: i can't find anything on your code so far, the only difference between yours and mine is i used explicit return in the `full_title` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on the same book, and am at the same chapter as you! I see the following:

```
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-"Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
+"Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
```

Rearranged:

```
--- expected
-"Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"

+++ actual
+"Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
```

The test expected "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App", but actually got "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App".

If you look at the help page in a browser, what shows up in the title bar? The help.html.erb looks right to me.

I also have the following for my app/helpers/application_helper.rb, is a little different from yours:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      page_title + " | " + base_title
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" is coming up in the title bar - all good now. the tutorial's getting interesting now!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my `full_title` method.

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def full_title(page_title = "")
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"

    line = page_title.empty? ? "" : " | "

    return "#{page_title}#{line}#{base_title}"
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, was going to ask for that. i'm AFK for the night (London time) but will test this out in the morning. much appreciated, David

Comment: all working fine now - using your code did the job. upvoted (but not showing as I'm still unworthy)